# Replace words in a string with the words defined as values in a hash

Tags: ruby

The aim is to replace specific words in a string by the values defined in the dictionary.

```
dictionary =
    {"Hello" => "hi",
    "to, two, too" => "2",
    "for, four" => "4",
    "be" => "b",
    "you" => "u",
    "at" => "@",
    "and" => "&"
}

def word_substituter(tweet)
    tweet_array = tweet.split(',') ##converting the string to array
    tweet_array.each do |word|
        if word === dictionary.keys ##if the words of array are equal to the keys of the dictionary
         word == dictionary.values ##then now the words are now the the values of the dictionary
         puts word
        end
      end 
    word.join(", ")
end

word_substituter("Hey guys, can anyone teach me how to be cool? I really want to be the best at everything, you know what I mean? Tweeting is super fun you guys!!!!")
```

I would appreciate the help. Could you explain it?

Comment: please, please put the code as text in the question, not a screenshot.

Comment: And to be clear, are you wanting that "to", "two", and "too" all be replaced by "2"?

Comment: yes and sorry about the image

Answer (score 0):

Naive words enumeration

```
DICTIONARY = {
  "Hello" => "hi",
  "to, two, too" => "2",
  "for, four" => "4",
  "be" => "b",
  "you" => "u",
  "at" => "@",
  "and" => "&"
}.freeze

def word_substituter(tweet)
  dict = {}
  DICTIONARY.keys.map { |k| k.split(', ') }.flatten.each do |w|
    DICTIONARY.each { |k, v| dict.merge!(w => v) if k.include?(w) }
  end

  tweet.split(' ').map do |s|
    dict.each { |k, v| s.sub!(/#{k}/, v) if s =~ /\A#{k}[[:punct:]]*\z/ }
    s
  end.join(' ')
end

word_substituter("Hey guys, I'm Robe too. Can anyone teach me how to be cool? I really want to be the best at everything, you know what I mean? Tweeting is super fun you guys!!!!")

# => "Hey guys, I'm Robe 2. Can anyone teach me how 2 b cool? I really want 2 b the best @ everything, u know what I mean? Tweeting is super fun u guys!!!!"
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like this provides a fairly simple solution to this:

```
DICTIONARY = {
  "Hello" => "hi",
  "to, two, too" => "2",
  "for, four" => "4",
  "be" => "b",
  "you" => "u",
  "at" => "@",
  "and" => "&"
}.freeze

def word_substituter(tweet)
  tweet.dup.tap do |t|
    DICTIONARY.each { |key, replacement| t.gsub!(/\b(#{key.split(', ').join('|')})\b/, replacement) }
  end
end

word_substituter("Hey guys, can anyone teach me how to be cool? I really want to be the best at everything, you know what I mean? Tweeting is super fun you guys!!!!")

# => "Hey guys, can anyone teach me how 2 b cool? I really want 2 b the best @ everything, u know what I mean? Tweeting is super fun u guys!!!!"
```

Breaking it down into steps:

- the method takes a tweet and creates a copy
- it passes this to [`tap`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/tap) so it's returned from the method call
- it iterates through the `DICTIONARY`
- transforms the `key` into a regex matcher (e.g. `/\b(to|two|too)\b/`)
- passes this to [`gsub!`](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/gsub%21) and replaces any matches with the `replacement`

If you want this to replace occurrence within words (e.g. `what => wh@`), you can remove the checks for word boundaries (`\b`) in the regex.

One gotcha is that if any of your dictionary's keys contain regex matchers, this would need a little rework: if you had `"goodbye." => 'later xxx'`, the dot would match any character and include it in what's replaced. [`Regexp.escape`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Regexp.html#method-c-escape) is your friend here.

Hope this helps - let me know how you get on.

Comment: Did this help at all @ZubairMaqsood?